# Performing Laravel Validation without $request

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to perform validation without passing the $request variable, would someone be able to provide what I pass through the validator function? My code is below

```
public function change($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->name = request("name");

        $user->date_of_birth = request("date");

        $user->email = request("email");

        $user->phone = request("phone");

        $user->address = request("address");

        $user->city = request("city");

        $user->postcode = request("postcode");

        $validator = Validator::make(request(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'email|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric',
            'address' => 'required|numeric',
            'postcode' => 'required|numeric',
            'city' => 'required'
        ]);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect("/user/edit")
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
        $user->save();

        return redirect('/user');
    }
```

Again, i am trying this without $request

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by passing an array, so `all()` returns all the fields passed, try using it like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make(request()->all(), ...
```

Another tip is to first make the validation then find the user and set its fields. The validation can be a guard in this case. You can also create a custom Form request and set the validation rules there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use facade to fetch that data and pass it to validator,

```
$input = Request::all();
```

Here is the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#retrieving-input).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the `$request` you can just use the `request()` helper instead. For example:

```php
$user = User::find($id);

$user->name = request("name");

$user->date_of_birth = request("date");

$user->email = request("email");

$user->phone = request("phone");

$user->address = request("address");

$user->city = request("city");

$user->postcode = request("postcode");

request()->validate([
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'email|string|max:255|unique:users',
    'phone' => 'required|numeric',
    'address' => 'required|numeric',
    'postcode' => 'required|numeric',
    'city' => 'required'
])

$user->save();

return redirect('/user');
```

That works fine unless you want to specifically handle failed validation in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use $request, please use request helper which can be used as  `Request::all();` or `request->all();`